# How do I match nodes on all matching connections?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'd like to return all encounters (p2) that have the same ICD9DX codes as the p1:Encounter. So if p1 has 3 ICD9DX codes, I'd like to find p2 nodes that have those same 3 codes. Ultimately I'd like to know how to write the query so it will return just p2 nodes that **only** have those same three codes and also how to write it so that it will return ones that have **at least** those three codes. I've tried figuring this out from the other questions that have been answered, but have been unsuccessful so far. Below is my latest iteration.

```
MATCH path=((p1:Encounter {PatientAccount: '1003149560'})-[:HasICD9Dx]-(i:ICD9DX)-[:HasICD9Dx]-(p2:Encounter))
WHERE ALL(p1 in tail(nodes(path)) WHERE ()-[:HasICD9Dx]->p1) 
RETURN p2
```

I'm brand new to Neo4j, so any commentary on the logic would be helpful. I've seen other posts that approach similar topics using WITH, but I'm struggling to understand the WITH clause. Maybe I just need to dig in and read the manual.

Comment: Is there anything important about specifically 3 codes, or do you just mean any  number of codes?

Comment: I can see the question being asked both ways: (1) which encounters have the exact same codes and no more and (2) which encounters have at least these codes. I think I figured it out though. I'll supply the answer I arrived at.

Comment: The WITH clause: is like RETURN, but you transfer data from one query part to another, only what you transfer is visible and you can do any projection, aggregation,filtering, ordering as you can do with RETURN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out (it seems). To return encounters that at least match the codes related to p1:

```
MATCH (p1:Encounter {PatientAccount: '1002844934'})-[:HasICD9Dx]-(i:ICD9DX)
WITH COUNT(i) AS codes, p1
MATCH (p2:Encounter)-[:HasICD9Dx]-(i:ICD9DX)-[:HasICD9Dx]-(p1)
WITH count(i) as foundCodes, codes, p2
WHERE foundCodes = codes
MATCH (p2)-[:HasICD9Dx]-(i:ICD9DX)
WITH count(i) as totalCodes, codes, p2
RETURN p2.PatientAccount, totalCodes
```

To return encounters that have the exact same codes as p1 and no more:

```
MATCH (p1:Encounter {PatientAccount: '1002844934'})-[:HasICD9Dx]-(i:ICD9DX)
WITH COUNT(i) AS codes, p1
MATCH (p2:Encounter)-[:HasICD9Dx]-(i:ICD9DX)-[:HasICD9Dx]-(p1)
WITH count(i) as foundCodes, codes, p2
WHERE foundCodes = codes
MATCH (p2)-[:HasICD9Dx]-(i:ICD9DX)
WITH count(i) as totalCodes, codes, p2
WHERE totalCodes = codes
RETURN p2.PatientAccount
```